# Focus is not being set to the child control when containing WPF User control gets focus

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

I have a WPF user control containing a Text box and a button. I have a form containing a grid where 
1st row contains the textbox 
2nd row contains the user control as discussed above and the 
3rd row contains another text box.
When the form loads the focus is set to text box in the 1st row. 
I need to set the focus to the text box inside the user control when focus is set to the user control. and on tab out the focus should be set to the button inside the user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) event in the user control and set the focus to the textbox with the [Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx) method. You can explicitly set the tab ordering inside your user control using [KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabindex.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Is your code following MVVM pattern?. If yes writing event handlers directly inside the view code behind may not be a good idea and it breaks the separation of concerns in MVVM. Instead create a behavior class and write event handlers inside the behavior and bind the behavior to the user control in the view.

Example code is shown below. I have a Canvas and inside cavas I have three text boxes. I need to set the focus inside the first text box when the cavas loads. Something similar to your scenario.

Behavior code

```
public  class CanvasLoadedBehavior : Behavior<Canvas>
{
    private Canvas _canvas;
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        _canvas = AssociatedObject as Canvas;
        if (_canvas.Name == "ReturnRefundCanvas")
        {

            _canvas.Loaded += _canvas_Loaded;
        }


    }

    void _canvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FocusNavigationDirection focusDirection = FocusNavigationDirection.Next;

        // MoveFocus takes a TraveralReqest as its argument.
        TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(focusDirection);
        UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
        if (elementWithFocus != null)
        {
            elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(request);
        }

    }

}
```

View Code for binding cavas to behavior.

```
<Canvas  Name="ReturnRefundCanvas" Height="200" Width="1466" DataContext="{Binding RefundSearchViewModel}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <b:CanvasLoadedBehavior />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <uc:Keyboard Canvas.Left="973" Canvas.Top="111" ToolTip="Keyboard" RenderTransformOrigin="-2.795,9.787"></uc:Keyboard>
                <Label  Style="{StaticResource Devlbl}" Canvas.Left="28" Content="Return and Refund Search" Canvas.Top="10" />
                <Image Height="30" Width="28" Canvas.Top="6" Canvas.Left="5" Source="pack://application:,,,/HomaKiosk;component/images/searchF.png">
                    <Image.OpacityMask>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/HomaKiosk;component/images/searchF.png"/>
                    </Image.OpacityMask>
                </Image>

                <Separator Height="4" Canvas.Left="6" Margin="0" Canvas.Top="35" Width="1007"/>

                <ContentControl Canvas.Top="45" Canvas.Left="21"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorMsg}"
                    Visibility="{Binding Error, Converter={c:StringNullOrEmptyToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                    Content="{Binding Error}" Width="992"></ContentControl>

                <Label  Style="{StaticResource Devlbl}" Canvas.Left="29" Name="FirstName" Content="First Name" Canvas.Top="90" />
                <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox  Style="{StaticResource AutoComp}" Height="32" Canvas.Left="33" ToolTip="First Name"  Canvas.Top="120" Width="205"                     Padding="10,5" TabIndex="1001"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"

                    Watermark=""
                    IconPlacement="Left"
                    IconVisibility="Visible"
                    Delay="100"

                    Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}" 
                    Provider="{Binding FirstNameSuggestions}">
                    <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Padding="5">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   FontWeight="Bold" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
                </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox>

                <Label Style="{StaticResource Devlbl}" Canvas.Left="250" Content="Last Name" Canvas.Top="90" />
                <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox  Style="{StaticResource AutoComp}" Height="32" ToolTip="Last Name" Canvas.Left="250"  Canvas.Top="120" Width="205" Padding="10,5"  TabIndex="1002"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Watermark=""
                    IconPlacement="Left"
                    IconVisibility="Visible"
                    Delay="100"
                   Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}" 
                    Provider="{Binding LastNameSuggestions}">
                    <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Padding="5">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   FontWeight="Bold" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
                </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox>

                <Label Style="{StaticResource Devlbl}" Canvas.Left="480" Content="Receipt No" Canvas.Top="90" />
                             <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox  Style="{StaticResource AutoComp}" Height="32" ToolTip="Receipt No" Canvas.Left="480"  Canvas.Top="120" Width="205" Padding="10,5"  TabIndex="1002"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Watermark=""
                    IconPlacement="Left"
                    IconVisibility="Visible"
                    Delay="100"
                    Text="{Binding ReceiptNo, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}" 
                    Provider="{Binding ReceiptIdSuggestions}">
                    <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Padding="5">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   FontWeight="Bold">

                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <b:AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior RegularExpression="^[0-9]+$" MaxLength="15" />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox>
                <!--<Label Style="{StaticResource Devlbl}" Canvas.Left="710" Content="Duration" Canvas.Top="79" />-->
                <!--<ComboBox AllowDrop="True" Canvas.Left="710" ToolTip="Duration" Canvas.Top="107" Width="205" TabIndex="1004"
                    Style="{StaticResource CommonComboBox}"      
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Durations}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}">

                </ComboBox>-->

                <Button Content="Search" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" ToolTip="Search" 
                    Canvas.Top="116" Canvas.Left="710" Cursor="Hand" 
                    Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" TabIndex="2001">
                </Button>
                <Button Content="Clear" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"  ToolTip="Clear"
                    Canvas.Top="116" Canvas.Left="840" Cursor="Hand" 
                    Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" TabIndex="2002">
                </Button>
                <Image Height="25" Width="25" Canvas.Top="175" Canvas.Left="25" Source="pack://application:,,,/HomaKiosk;component/images/chkpending.png"/>
                <Label  Style="{StaticResource LegendLbl}" Canvas.Left="50" Content="Check Returned and Payment Pending" Canvas.Top="178" />
                <Image Height="25" Width="25" Canvas.Top="175" Canvas.Left="300" Source="pack://application:,,,/HomaKiosk;component/images/chkrepaid.png"/>
                <Label  Style="{StaticResource LegendLbl}" Canvas.Left="325" Content="Repaid" Canvas.Top="178" />
                <Image Height="25" Width="25" Canvas.Top="175" Canvas.Left="395" Source="pack://application:,,,/HomaKiosk;component/images/refund.png"/>
                <Label  Style="{StaticResource LegendLbl}" Canvas.Left="415" Content="Refunded" Canvas.Top="178" />
                 </Canvas>
```